# Fortran OpenMP calculation for partial sums

Tags: fortran, openmp, reduction

I am very new to Fortran and am working through an exercise that involves summing numbers in parallel through OpenMP.

I have been given that the following code correctly calculates the sum of numbers in parallel through OpenMP

```
!$omp parallel do private (I)
!$omp+ reduction(+:totals)
do I=1,100
    totals = totals + localsum(I)
enddo
!$omp end parallel do
```

If I adjust the above code so that I can run it in my own Fortran program, I produce

```
Program test
    implicit none
    real totals
    double precision, dimension (1 : 100) :: localsum
    integer I

    !$omp parallel do private (I)
    !$omp+ reduction(+:totals)
    do I=1,100
        localsum(I)=I
        totals = totals + localsum(I)
    enddo
    !$omp end parallel do
    print *, 'The calculated sum total is', totals
end
```

This program returns

```
The calculated sum total is   5050.00000
```

However, I'm not sure why I needed to add the additional line for

```
localsum(I)=I
```

when the original code didn't have this line. I notice that if I remove

```
!$omp+ reduction(+:totals)
```

Then

```
Program test
    implicit none
    real totals
    double precision, dimension (1 : 100) :: localsum
    integer I

    !$omp parallel do private (I)
    do I=1,100
        localsum(I)=I
        totals = totals + localsum(I)
    enddo
    !$omp end parallel do
    print *, 'The calculated sum total is', totals
end
```

returns

```
 The calculated sum total is   5050.00000
```

when the calculated total should be wrong. Including the reduction, `!$omp+ reduction(+:totals)`, should be necessary to compute the correct totals.

Is there an alternative way of adjusting the do loop to match the original code provided? I'm not sure why I had to change

```
do I=1,100
    totals = totals + localsum(I)
enddo
```

to

```
do I=1,100
    localsum(I)=I
    totals = totals + localsum(I)
enddo
```

in order to calculate the local sum.

Comment: Without `localsum(I)=I` you aren't defining the array before trying to sum with `totals = totals + localsum(I)`.  Do you mean that you try `totals = totals + I` instead?

Comment: I think that `localsum(I)=I` is necessary to run the program in parallel. If I adjust `totals=totals + I` then that would be a sequential implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With or without the  `!$omp+ reduction(+:totals)` the executed code is different.

Without this directive, you directly update the global var `totals`. This may work (and in your example it worked), but it far from being guaranteed. The problem is that this may lead to races.

Assume thread a and thread b want to update this var. They need:
1. to fetch the var from memory
2. to update it  in the processor
3. to write it back to memory

What will be the relative order of these operations in threads a and b? It is unspecified.
If the order is 1a2a3a1b2b3b, there is no problem.
If it is 1a1b2a2b3a3b there will be a problem:  1a1b(threads a et b fetch the same value)2a2b(they update it more or less simultaneously)3a3b(thread a writes its result and it is overwritten by thread b value).

To avoid that, you can have atomic operations, that guarantee that the read-modify-write cycle cannot be interrupted but they are very expensive and may slow down significantly the execution time.

To avoid that, you must use reductions. The line `!$omp+ reduction(+:totals)` tells openmp to do a reduction in a safe and efficient way. What will actually be done is

1. setup a hidden local var to do the accumulation in the partial loop
2. at every iteration of the loop perform the accumulation in this local var
3. at the end accumulate these partial results to the global var `totals` in a safe way: an atomic operation will be performed in such a way that the global var is properly updated and avoid races between threads.

There are still atomic updates, but their number is reduced and the accumulation is mostly performed by fast local operations.

Concerning the usefulness of the line `localsum(I)=I`, it is required is the vector `localsum` is not initialized previously. But if the goal is just to add the first integers, you can just use

```
do I=1,100
    totals = totals + I
enddo
```

The performance will be improved and the result identical. And both loops are parallelized in a similar way.

Comment: Writing `!$omp+ reduction(+:totals)` with the do loop changed to `totals = totals + I` sometimes returns the wrong answer. The total sum is sometimes calculated as 4679.00000 instead of 5050.0000. This is what I am confused about - if this was correct, it would always return 5050.0000.

Comment: Although, I think that I should make a new question for this observation. The code clearly must include `!$omp+ reduction(+:totals)`. So, I must indirectly be doing something else wrong.

Comment: I will make a new question for my observation. Thanks for your extremely helpful answer.

Comment: Sorry, but the comment is incorrect, as the format of the OpenMP directive is syntactically incorrect. The statements about the race conditions are correct though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a duplicate of [Odd results with !$omp reduction in Fortran OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389737/odd-results-with-omp-reduction-in-fortran-openmp/55390898).

According to the OpenMP specification (see page 42), the proper continuation of an OpenMP directive is to use `&` at the end of the previous line and `!$omp&` on the continuation line (the ampersand in `!$omp&` is optional).  So, so your code should look like this:

```
Program test
    implicit none
    real totals
    integer I
    integer, dimension(100) :: localsum
    !$omp parallel do private (I) &
    !$omp& reduction(+:totals)
        do I=1,100
            localsum(I)=I
            totals = totals + localsum(I)
        enddo
    !$omp end parallel do
    print *, 'The calculated sum total is', totals
end
```

As the compiler ignored the continuation line defining the reduction over the `totals` variable, you've got an arbitrary result.  With the proper continuation added, I'm getting the correct result:

```
The calculated sum total is   5050.000
```

Comment: If a new question is a duplicate, do not post two exactly same answers, vote for close as duplicate or comment.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I do not have enough Stackoverflow-fu yet to do that.

Comment: Just do not post the same answer under multiple question. You can aalways comment that the question is a duplicate.